# Laravel 5 Class 'Prettus\Repository\Providers\Repository ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, repository

I'm studing about **Repository Design Pattern** in Laravel and I'm using https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository to do it.

But after I copy/paste folder prettus in my project and add in my **config/app.php** **Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class** to the end of the providers array I find a problem:

```
Class 'Prettus\Repository\Providers\Repository ServiceProvider' not found
```

After that, the project can't run. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you run `composer require prettus/l5-repository` ?

Comment: I have just upload my question you can help me . Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581645/laravel-5-sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't copy/paste the source folder in your project.

Try following the instructions as stated in the Github documentation:

> composer require prettus/l5-repository

After the installation finishes you can include the Class in the ServiceProvider array and then you have to publish the configuration:

> php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: Thanks fixed this .But i have new error . After i run php artisan make:repository Post . I have 2 file in folder Repositories and in controller i run it . But it not working **Target [App\Repositories\PostRepository] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\DataController]**

Comment: I invite you to accept the answer if it helped you solving the original problem. To help you with the new problem we would need to see the code of your controller, repository and full trace of the exception in a new question

Comment: I have just upload my question you can help me . Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581645/laravel-5-sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found