# Laravel 5 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, repository

I'm studing about Repository Design Pattern in Laravel and I'm using https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository to do it.

I think i install success in my project . But when i run code with repository i have some problem

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'test.nhanviens' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `nhanviens`)

**Table in my database is Nhanvien not Nhanviens**

Here in my code

**NhanvienRepository.php**

```
<?php

   namespace App\Repositories;

   use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\RepositoryInterface;

   /**
    * Interface NhanvienRepository
    * @package namespace App\Repositories;
    */
   interface NhanvienRepository extends RepositoryInterface
   {
       //
   }
```

**NhanvienRepositoryEloquent.php**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Repositories;

use Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use App\Repositories\NhanvienRepository;
use App\Entities\Nhanvien;
use App\Validators\NhanvienValidator;

/**
 * Class NhanvienRepositoryEloquent
 * @package namespace App\Repositories;
 */
class NhanvienRepositoryEloquent extends BaseRepository implements NhanvienRepository
{
    /**
     * Specify Model class name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function model()
    {
        return Nhanvien::class;
    }



    /**
     * Boot up the repository, pushing criteria
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->pushCriteria(app(RequestCriteria::class));
    }
}
```

**DataController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\nhanvien;
use App\Repositories\NhanvienRepository;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(NhanvienRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function DanhSach(){
        var_dump($this->repository->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update App\Entities\Nhanvien?

Comment: public function model() { return "App\\Nhanvien"; }

Comment: i have just add your function but my code still not work :)

Comment: var_dump(\App\Nhanvien::all()); and show me error or not?

Comment: i got same errror :(

Comment: check model Nhanvien.php correct $table or check your databse table name

Comment: Check .env connect correct database name

Comment: everything correct?

Comment: Yes everthing is correct :(

Comment: what's database name? test ?

Comment: Yes. My database is test and here code in my env file DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Answer (score 5):

from App\Nhanvien.php Add this variable to the class:

```
 protected $table = 'nhanvien';
```

Explanation: The "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the nhanvien model stores records in the nhanviens table.

Comment: thank you . But in my model i have your code . I got same error .I think it not true . :)

Comment: your model class extends what? Eloquent, Model or Ardent?

Comment: My model extends Model :D

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [official Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) you need to specifically set the table name in your Model definition. That is, in your App\Nhanvien.php file set the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nhanvien extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Nhanvien';
}
```

or use

```
protected $table = 'nhanvien';
```

instead if your table name is full lowercase.

Comment: Yes my table in database everything is lowercase

Comment: when you online please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your migration file, maybe you are using **`Schema::table`**, like this:

> Schema::table('table_name', function ($table)  {
>       // ... });

**If you want to create a new table you must use Schema::create:**

```
 Schema::create('table_name', function ($table)  {
     // ... });
```

See the [Laravel migration documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-tables) for more information.

If you are using `Schema::create` then please provide the contents of your migration file.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I've got rid of similar error by executing the command

```
php artisan config:cache
```